# Django tests failing on CI after adding django-bower

Tags: django, selenium, continuous-integration, bower

I have a Django project where I have a few frontend dependencies and so I tried adding django-bower to help me manage them.

I have replaced the previous dependencies with the bower versions and everything seems to be working fine. I'm running my tests with Selenium and when I run them locally, they are passing.

However, when I proceed to test on a CI server, the Selenium tests are failing, with an error message that it is unable to locate an element on the page. This is a form element and I am sure it is there.

I'm trying to figure out why the tests are passing locally but failing on the CI server. Before adding django-bower all tests were passing also in the CI server.

Here is a snippet of the relevant part in the Django settings

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
    # Compressor finder
    "compressor.finders.CompressorFinder",
    # Django bower finder
    "djangobower.finders.BowerFinder",
    )

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads')

MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'

BOWER_COMPONENTS_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'js')

BOWER_INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'fontawesome#4.3.0',
    'jquery-validation#1.13.1',
    'magnific-popup#1.0.0',
    'masonry#3.2.2',
    'materialize#0.95.3',
)
```

The bower components are installed in `static/js/bower_components`

The error message provided on the CI server is

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with id 'message-form'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"93","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:60555","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"id\", \"sessionId\": \"bb17c920-c5dd-11e4-9c9b-e7fbd91dc2da\", \"value\": \"message-form\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/bb17c920-c5dd-11e4-9c9b-e7fbd91dc2da/element"}}
```

Any help would really be appreciated. I've Googled everything I can think of and can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Bower with Django projects, but I don't used django-bower. I use it standalone (via `bower install`), have it store front-end deps in static/bower-components, and refer to that path in templates with the `{% static %}` template tag. No idea whether doing that would affect your odd test results, but worth a try.

Comment: I'm leaning towards this approach. Thanks for your recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

This would be still a guess, but I've seen these kind of problems solved by tweaking your tests and adding an [`Explicit Wait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits). Instead of just:

```
form = driver.find_element_by_id('message-form')
```

use:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

form = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "message-form")))
```

Basically, you are waiting for the element to become present on a page for 10 seconds, checking every 500 ms. If the element would not become present in 10 seconds, it would throw `TimeoutException`.

Comment: Still not really working. Tests still failing on the CI server.